# Apache NiFi OutOfMemoryError while generating large FlowFiles

Tags: java, out-of-memory, apache-nifi

I am using Apache NiFi 0.4.1 and Java 7 on Centos 7 and am trying to create a flow file based on some incoming data. I am running in to a "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" exception due to the large amount of data I am generating.

This, as far as I can tell, is because the output stream provided by NiFi when writing to the flow file is a ByteArrayOutputStream and so the data is stored in memory. I can understand why this would happen, yet I am able to use GetFile/PutFile to process a much larger file (I tried loading a 10Gb file, logging its attributes and writing it to a different location, which worked). Is there something I am missing here? Is there a way to write much larger flow files? Or does NiFi 0.5.0 change anything to help me?

NOTE: I don't think increasing the amount of java heap space available will fix my problem

Comment: I would have given a comment saying to increase the java heap if you had not written the note lol. Must the data be stored in memory? Perhaps writing  everything to a file to later process it would be better? Idk, was just a little suggestion.

Comment: I had just tried writing it to a file and then loading it into the new flow file the same way as GetFile seems to do it (using importFrom), but it still fails.

Comment: Ok then I am sorry, I don't know it.

Comment: OK, so that did actually work, just not whilst unit testing!

Comment: Oh so the problem is the unit test?

Comment: The unit test provides exactly the same data as when using the the NiFi application and all it does is run testRunner.run(1) on it. So a wild guess would be that the unit tests always use in memory data structures whereas the NiFi application does something clever with the files when using importFrom()?...
(My original approach without writing to disk first doesn't work outside of the unit tests either)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As highlighted in the comments, the unit testing framework uses a variant of the content repository where everything is stored in memory to facilitate speed when testing.  Indeed, if the content is large, you are directly exerting pressure on the heap.  In the actual application, these items are read to/from the content repository via streams to/from the disk.

These problems could also arise in the core framework if the case arises where extensions are reading contents in-memory in lieu of using streaming for large files.